# Is it possible to use macOS Accessibility API features from a CLI or library?

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility-api

I am working on an application that needs to leverages macOS Accessibility APIs to read the selected text in any application. I will call a Swift library from Rust via FFI.

I am able to get a POC working as part of a SwiftUI application, but when I try the same code from a command line Swift application (or call it via FFI), I can no longer access information about other applications.

For example, using the function below, I can get the text selected in Messages if I trigger it via my SwiftUI app. If I run it as a command line app, it still prints `trusted: true`, but `AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute as CFString, &focusedElement)` returns a `cannotComplete` AXError.

```
func getSelectedText() {
    print("trusted: \(AXIsProcessTrusted())")
    sleep(2) // switch windows and select text
    
    let systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()
    
    var focusedElement: AnyObject?
    let err = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute as CFString, &focusedElement)
    
    if err != .success {
        print("Unable to get focused element: ", String(reflecting: err))
        return
    }
    
    var selectedText: AnyObject?
    AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(focusedElement as! AXUIElement, kAXSelectedTextAttribute as CFString, &selectedText)
    
    print(selectedText as? String ?? "No selected text found")
}
```

I'm new to programming for macOS in general and would appreciate any direction here. Thanks!

Comment: After working on this for a while longer I was able to get something to work by replacing `let systemWideElement = AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()` with
  

`guard let frontMostApp = NSWorkspace.shared.frontmostApplication else { return (nil, nil) }; 
let appRef = AXUIElementCreateApplication(frontMostApp.processIdentifier)`
  

I'm not sure why this worked and `AXUIElementCreateSystemWide()` didn't seem to - I'd appreciate any pointers here!

Comment: Oh my god. How did you find that? I was in exactly same situation and you found perfect solution!